# Octopress / Jekyll internal links broken

Tags: hyperlink, jekyll, octopress

I'm using Octopress / Jekyll with the the Justin Kelly theme. The internal links in Recent Posts on the sidebar work fine locally but break in production.

Specifically, the links manifest after the current path, for example:

```
/twilio-text-to-speech-in-rails-4/twilio-text-to-speech-in-rails-4
```

which should really be just:

```
/twilio-text-to-speech-in-rails-4/
```

Again it works find locally. I have permalinks set on every blog post page, to continue the example:

```
permalink: "how-i-built-poemtoday"
```

And in `_config.yml`:

```
permalink: /:title/
```

Have tried a bunch of things, removing the permalinks, reverting to the original config, but nothing works!

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out. Jekyll wanted a starting forward flash in the permalink.

```
permalink: "/how-i-built-poemtoday"
```